# How many bluetooth connections can an iPhone or iPad support at one time?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum number of peripherals on CoreBluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469502/maximum-number-of-peripherals-on-corebluetooth)

We are building a suite of BTLE gadgets that communicate to an iOS device and interact with an app we are writing.  How many can we connect at one time?