# How many devices we can pair via Bluetooth to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Can anyone tell me how many devices can we pair via Bluetooth to iPhone at a time..need help..till now i have not got the exact number.

Comment: In a Bluetooth piconet one master can communicate up to 7 active slaves, there can be some other up to 248 devices which are in sleep mode (may participate to communication actively when another active device goes into sleep mode). 

In Bluetooth scatternets (interconnected piconets) number of devices are not limited. Some slaves used as a bridge by participating two or more piconets. One of the most advanced topology defined for Bluetooth scatternets is Cube Connected Cycles architecture.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As it stands in iOS 6.1.4, the current limit for Bluetooth Low Energy devices is 10 simultaneous CONNECTIONS (at least on the NRF8002 chipset). Although the BLE spec says it can in theory have an infinite number of connections, the connection will time out when you try to add an 11th device.

As for the pairing table, I've previously had two additional a2dp devices in my pairing table(not connected) and 10 current BLE connections as the maximum. So that is a total of 12 devices in the pairing table on an iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.4. You could probably have more devices listed in the pairing table, but the one definite is 10 connections is the current max.

Comment: That seems consistent with the 10-20 Bluetooth LE device limit that Bluegiga quoted when I talked to them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13654052/19679

Comment: Hi what about Bluetooth 2.1 devices?

Comment: @tdevoy: Any source for the "10" number?

Comment: @boardbite personal testing plus confirmation with bluetooth team at apple. This is with the 10 ble devices actually being paired as well as connected.

Comment: @tdevoy: Good to know; opens up a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

(I know this is an old question, but) Apple say

> The official Bluetooth specifications say seven is the maximum number of Bluetooth devices that can be connected to your Mac at once.
>   However, three to four devices is a practical limit, depending on the types of devices used. Some devices require more Bluetooth data, so they're more demanding than other devices. Data-intensive devices might reduce the total number of devices that can be active at the same time.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201171

(And, I know this is for a Mac and not an iPhone. But, *perhaps* this also holds here).

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth specification allows more than one device to connect at a time, but it's not straightforward, as it is dependent on the type of device and the service profile it provides.  
For example, you can have a bluetooth keyboard, mouse, and headset connected at the same time, and an A2DP (Advanced Audio Distribution Profile) device to stream music, but you can't have two devices that performing the same service profile connected at the same time.

More in detail info: [Bluetooth Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth)