# How many bluetooth (2.1 and LE) devices can be connected simultaneously to an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, bluetooth

How many bluetooth 2.1 and bluetooth LE devices can be connected simultaneously to an iPad?

I have found out that only 3 bluetooth 2.1 devices can be connected simultaneously to an iPad. What about bluetooth LE devices? Is the number the same or higher?

PS: I am talking about "connected and communicating" with the iPad. I am not talking about "pairing".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth can connect `8` devices at total, so `7` may connect to You.

[Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth)

Please note that interference doesn't allow to comfortable use of even `3`.

Comment: Is it a total of 8 for both 2.1 and BLE?

Comment: @VanDuTran: It is said in documentation that BLE supports unlimited connections in master mode. But as far as I know, people have problems with even 2, probably because of software. And let's be honest... 100mW low range connection and unlimited devices? Come on, marketing bulls**t.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of connected BLE devices is 10. Reference this answer for more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17282862/2341249