# How to get the paired BLE device count?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Description - How I can get the number of BLE connection in iOS.
I want to restrict a user to add more BLE sensor after a particular number of BLE connection. I want to get the number of a BLE connection a device can handle.

Comment: Your app is managing the connections, you can limit it that way by keeping track of the identifiers your user has registered in your app and not connecting to additional peripherals after the limit is reached.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for quick reply, I want the number of peripheral connection a device can handle, Whatever I have read as of now from that I know that theoretically there is no limit on Number of BLE connection an app can handle. What I want a total number of BLE connection other than my peripherals. like if there is a music system, then there might be sensor tags etc. so how much connection a system can handle that's what I want.

Comment: @Nik Could you get the answer to this question by any other means? I am also looking for the same.

Comment: @Amruta Not yet, I am too searching for the limit of connection can BLE hold.  here is what I found : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469502/maximum-number-of-peripherals-on-corebluetooth

Here are few links mentioning the count:
1. https://lists.apple.com/archives/bluetooth-dev/2012/Jun/msg00093.html
2. https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/4421/max-no-of-devices-for-ios-7/

Answer (score 0):

A connection represents state, not traffic. The count of connections will be bound by either memory or the data structures used by the Bluetooth stack to manage them, both unknown. My answer is, "As many as it can and no more."

Packets represent traffic and each is handled one at a time. From this perspective, my answer is, "One."

However, if a packet cannot be processed out of the critical paths in the chip and protocol stack fast enough to begin processing the next packet, packets can be dropped. Experience has shown these critical paths in iOS are dependent on the traffic's packet size and rate. Additionally, other devices in the area not connected to your BLE stack may be flooding the radio spectrum and causing packet collisions outside the stack. I have seen BLE traffic go to hell with an excess of 20 connections and as few as one. From this perspective my answer is, "It depends."